# How does negation as failure work with variables?

Tags: algorithms, prolog, logic-programming

Let's say we have the following rule:

```
p -: X ≠ Y, X = Y
```

Stating that $\forall x.y. x \neq y \land x = y \implies p$. Now let us suppose that we are searching for a proof of $p$. Such a proof does not exist, of course, but we will search for it.

Our starting goal is `p`. We replace it with the subgoals `X ≠ Y` and `X = Y`. To resolve `X ≠ Y`, we use negation as failure. We must show that exists an $x$ and $y$ such that $x = y$ is unprovable. So we know have a goal of `X = Y`. Since $x$ and $y$ are not the same variable (remember, $x$ and $y$ were bound by the quantifier of the *top level* rule), there is no way to resolve $x = y$. So we fail to show $x = y$, and the subgoal `X ≠ Y` is resolved. We now resolve the subgoal `X = Y`. This is done by unification, which means we set `Y := X`. Since all subgoals have been resolved, the original goal `p` has succeeded, with the solution `X := X` and `Y := X`.

However, this is obviously incorrect since $p$ should not be provable. $x \neq y \land x = y$ is always false, so we can not use the rule to deduce it.

The problem seems to be that negation as failure is not actually negation. Being unable to show that $x \neq y$ does not mean it is false. Resolving something like I did above "loses" consequences of negated statements.

What is the correct way to resolve rules like the above?